# Associating two nodes at the same level of hierarchy with PL/SQL

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

I’m currently working with Oracle PL/SQL in Oracle 11g.
I have two kinds of XML that I work from.

Following a sample of the two types of XML and the extraction I've done so far.

TYPE 1 XML:

```
<ListItens1 xmlns=“xpto”>
<item id=”1”>
    <product type=”fruit”>
        <model> Apple </model>
        <date>02/19/2013</date>
        <year>2013</year>
    </product>
</item >
<item id=”2”>
    <product type=”notebook”>
        <model> Vostro </model>
        <date>02/19/2013</date>
        <year> 2013 </year>
    </product>
</item>
</ListItens1>
```

TYPE 2 XML:

```
<ListItens2 xmlns=“xpto”>
 <item>1</item>
 <product type=”fruit”>
    <model> Apple </model>
    <date>02/19/2013</date>
    <year>2013</year>
 </product>
 <item>2</item>
 <product type=”notebook”>
    <model> Vostro </model>
    <date>02/19/2013</date>
    <year> 2013 </year>
 </product>
<ListItens2>
```

Those XML are being inserted to a Table that has a field called Archive of type XMLTYPE.

```
CREATE TABLE XML_PRODUCT ( ID_XML NUMBER, DATA DATE, ARCHIVE XMLType);
```

When the XML are of type 1 I’m doing like this with no problem:

```
SELECT 
  ExtractValue( value( NFe ) , '/item/@id', 'xmlns="xpto' ) ID,
  ExtractValue( value( NFe ) , '/item/product/@type', 'xmlns="xpto' ) TYPE,
  ExtractValue( value( NFe ) , '/item/product/model', 'xmlns="xpto' ) MODEL,
  ExtractValue( value( NFe ) , '/item/product/date'', 'xmlns="xpto' ) DATE,
  ExtractValue( value( NFe ) , '/item/product/year'', 'xmlns="xpto' ) YEAR,
FROM XML_PRODUCT,
  TABLE( XMLSequence( Extract ( ARCHIVE,  '/listItens1/item', 'xpto' ) ) ) NFe
WHERE ID_XML = 1;
```

It results in:

```
 ID |  TYPE     | MODEL  |    DATE    | YEAR 
-----------------------------------------------
 1  |  fruit    | Apple  | 02/19/2013 | 2013   
 2  |  notebook | Vostro | 02/19/2013 | 2013
```

But for the TYPE 2 I don't know how to do the association between ITEM and PRODUCT because they are in the same hierarchical level in the XML.

It is possible to extract the product data associating with the item without modifying the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extract the item count first, and then get the product occurance from that.

```
select id_xml, 
       extractvalue(xml, '/item['||r||']', 'xmlns="xpto"' ) item,
       extractvalue(xml, '/product['||r||']/@type', 'xmlns="xpto"' ) type,
       extractvalue( xml , '/product['||r||']/model', 'xmlns="xpto"' ) model,
       extractvalue(xml , '/product['||r||']/date', 'xmlns="xpto"' ) dte,
       extractvalue( xml , '/product['||r||']/year', 'xmlns="xpto"' ) year
  from (select id_xml, extract(archive, '/ListItens2/*', 'xmlns="xpto"') xml, rownum r
           from xml_product,
                table(xmlsequence(extract(archive, '/ListItens2/item', 'xmlns="xpto"'))) nfe
          where id_xml = xxx);
```